# Excel Crashing when Handling Large Amounts of Bloomberg Data (Refresh issue)

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I have a workbook which contains data points on all equities globally all retrieved using combinations of BDH/BDP Bloomberg formulae, and as one can imagine, this is a lot of data (the workbook is ~20mb).

When opening the workbook and Bloomberg tries to update, both Excel and Bloomberg freeze and then ultimately crash due to the amount of data requests sent at one time.

Is anyone aware of a workaround that would stagger the refreshes of certain sections of the page, or to deal with this issue in some way? I am aware that I can untick 'real time updates' but I will need to refresh this file from time to time, and don't want to encounter the freezing issue each time.

Comment: 20 MB is not that big. Is it only one sheet? In that case I would try to copy the data into a new workbook and recreate the formulae to see if the problem is not that the file has become corrupted (happens sometimes with the BB Addin).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Before opening this file, in the Bloomberg tab:

1. Uncheck "Real-Time Updates".
2. Options, Functions tab, uncheck all "Update on File Open".

Then open the big file, select the cells you want to refresh and click the arrow under "Refresh Worksheet" and then "Refresh Selection".